# Как по нажатию inline кнопки вытаскивать значение из сообщения?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть бот телеграм на aiogram. При нажатии inline кнопки бот должен писать юзеру "Введите 1 число", потом записывать значение, которое ему прислал юзер в переменную а, и второе число в переменную b (Значения должно быть в int). Если значения не int, то отклонять их. Пытался сделать так:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button9') 
async def handle_a(message : types.message):
    if message.text == 'Назад':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, reply_markup=kb.inline_menu_r)
```

Но пока знаю только, как реагировать на "Назад" и то он не отправляет меню, отвечает то же самое, что и при неизвестной/ого текста/команде.
Нужно также как-то проверять в int значения или нет.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот полностью рабочии ваш код. Чтобы реализовать то что вы хотите, нужно использовать так назваемый FSM - Finit State Machine. Об FSM и других плюшках aiogram вы можете узнать из этой книги - https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/, там один товарищ обьясняет доступным языком всякие возможности. Я написал в некоторых местах коментарии-пояснении к коду, чтобы было вам понятно

```
from aiogram import types, Bot, executor, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize FSM storage
memory_storage = MemoryStorage()

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token="BOT TOKEN HERE")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=memory_storage)

class InputUserData(StatesGroup):
    step_1 = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def startpg(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('button9', callback_data = 'button9')
    keyboard_markup.row(button9)
    await message.reply('Добро пожаловать!\nЭто бот тестер, нажмите на Inline кнопку ниже', reply_markup=keyboard_markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button9') 
async def handle_a(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.edit_text('Введите значение переменной a:')
    await InputUserData.step_1.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=InputUserData.step_1, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def questionnaire_state_1_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as user_data:
    # Здесь user_data является хранилищем (а точнее словарем), куда можно сохранять определенные данные и вытаскивать если нужно в любой момент
        user_data['input_user'] = message.text.replace('\n',' ') # Вы возможно спросите - для чего нужен здесь replace, он нужен в случае если юзер умудрится написать значение переменной a на двух строках, у меня на практике такое было несколько раз

    a = user_data['input_user']

    await message.reply(f"Значение переменной a: {a}")

    await state.finish() # Оканчиваем наш FSM опрос от пользывателя

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: Скриншот успешной работы бота]

RTFM и Удачи Вам!